# Utilizar ficheros de otro virtual host

Tags: php, apache, plesk

> Resumen

Necesito que desde un virtual host, se puedan acceder a los ficheros php de otro virtual host.

> Entorno

- CentOS 7
- Plesk Onyx
- PHP 7.2

> Escenario

Tengo el siguiente escenario (se sustituyen datos reales):

- api.dominio1.com (Core de la API, clases y funcionamiento de la API)
- api.dominio2.com (Sirve la API tanto a dominio2.com como a la APP móvil)
- dominio2.com (Frontal web)

En el api.dominio1.com tengo lo que es el motor básico de la API y necesito poder cargar ficheros de este sitio en api.dominio2.com

Esto lo hago así, por que de cara a futuro abra más dominios que tiran de api.dominio1.com, de esta manera no tendré que repetir código cada vez que un nuevo servicio se genere, tirando siempre de api.dominio1.com además, si se modifica el código no tendré que ir luego actualizándolo en todos los demás dominios.

> Problema

Cuando hago un `require_once` del index.php de api.dominio1.com desde api.dominio2.com lanza el siguiente error:

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/vhosts/dominio1.com/api.dominio1.com/index.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/dominio2.com/:/tmp/) in /var/www/vhosts/dominio2.com/api.dominio2.com/index.php on line 4\nPHP message: PHP Warning: require_once(/var/www/vhosts/dominio1.com/api.dominio1.com/index.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /var/www/vhosts/dominio2.com/api.dominio2.com/index.php on line 4\nPHP message: PHP Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/vhosts/dominio1.com/api.dominio1.com/index.php' (include_path='.:/opt/plesk/php/7.2/share/pear') in /var/www/vhosts/dominio2.com/api.dominio2.com/index.php on line 4\n'
```

Entiendo que el problema es la directiva openbasedir, la cual me gustaría mantener para todo el servidor y agregar una excepción a este dominio.

> Código actual

Tengo el siguiente código en un fichero vhost.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/dominio1.com/api.dominio1.com>
php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/dominio1.com/api.dominio1.com:/tmp:/var/www/vhosts/dominio1.com/api.dominio1.com"
</Directory>
```

Después de introducir el vhost.conf mediante SSH hago los pasos necesarios para reconfigurar y recargar apache.

El servidor es propio y solo alojamos proyectos nuestros, por lo que la solución más sencilla sería desactivar el openbasedir para todo el hosting, aunque no me gustaría para nada esa opción.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer va en contra de la filosofía de los virtual hosts. Yo te recomiendo una de estas dos soluciones:

1. Publicar la API en api.dominio1.com, con claves de acceso que solo estarán en el código fuente de los demás dominios que utilicen la API.
2. Si quieres tener el código fuente de la API en cada proyecto (no te lo recomiendo), puedes crear una librería y publicarla en Github y Packagist. En cada proyecto requieres la librería con Composer y luego es cuestión de hacer un `composer update` cuando actualices la librería.

Comment: Hola jotaelesalinas, aunque agradezco las sugerencias que me indicas, la metodología que quiero seguir ya la tengo clara y la consulta es como hacer funcionar la regla que pongo como "Código actual". Sobre la filosofía de virtual host, ir en contra sería desactivar por completo el open_basedir, pero dar acceso concreto y controlado en un caso puntual que entiendo no es tan grave y existen muchos casos que se pueda dar esta necesidad.

Comment: Ok, espero que encuentres pronto la respuesta adecuada.